WSL上でファイルを削除しても、すぐに空ファイルが作成されてしまう現象は、何が原因か？
環境

Windows 11
WSL

> wsl --version
WSL バージョン: 2.2.4.0
カーネル バージョン: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg バージョン: 1.0.61
MSRDC バージョン: 1.2.5326
Direct3D バージョン: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore バージョン: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows バージョン: 10.0.22631.3810


PS > wsl -l -v
  NAME              STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu            Running         2
  docker-desktop    Stopped         2


WSL上のOSはUbuntu 22.04

$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-4FVMCJ6 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

背景
WSL上のUbuntuでPythonアプリケーションを開発しています。
worskapceディレクトリをVSCode Dev Containersを起動させて開発しています。
コンテナではpoetryを使っています。poetryで作った仮想環境はworkspace/.devcontainer/venvに作成されます。このディレクトリは、コンテナでは.venv/bin/にマウントされています。
状況
きっかけは忘れましたが、~/workspace/.devcontainer/venv/bin/pythonは空のファイルでした。
したがって、一度削除して再度poetryで仮想環境を作ろうとしました。
しかし、rmコマンドで削除してもすぐにファイルが作成されました。以下の事実から、「pythonファイルを削除したらすぐにまたファイルが作成されてしまう」と判断しました。

rmコマンドは失敗しなかった
statコマンドでファイル作成日時（Birth）は、rmコマンドで削除した後の日時である

yuji@DESKTOP:~/workspace/.devcontainer/venv/bin$ stat python
  File: python
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 810h/2064d      Inode: 63940       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    yuji)   Gid: ( 1000/    yuji)
Access: 2024-07-04 18:47:11.109974106 +0900
Modify: 2024-07-04 18:47:11.109974106 +0900
Change: 2024-07-04 18:47:11.109974106 +0900
 Birth: 2024-07-04 18:47:11.109974106 +0900

yuji@DESKTOP:~/workspace/.devcontainer/venv/bin$ rm python

yuji@DESKTOP:~/workspace/.devcontainer/venv/bin$ stat python
  File: python
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 810h/2064d      Inode: 63940       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    yuji)   Gid: ( 1000/    yuji)
Access: 2024-07-04 18:48:33.619949058 +0900
Modify: 2024-07-04 18:48:33.619949058 +0900
Change: 2024-07-04 18:48:33.619949058 +0900
 Birth: 2024-07-04 18:48:33.619949058 +0900

pythonファイルが削除できなくなったきっかけ
Windowsのファイルエクスプローラで、~/workspace/.devcontainerディレクトリをコピーや削除を実行しました。
たしか、ファイルエクスプローラ上で\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\yuji\src_workspace\.devcontainer`を\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\yuji\workspace`にコピーしました。
そのときに何かしらのエラーが出た気がします。
そのあとから、pythonファイルだけ削除できない（削除してもすぐにファイルが作成される）ように見えました。
試したこと
ターミナルをすべて閉じてwslを終了させましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。
Windowsを再起動したら、pythonファイルを削除することができ、解決しました。
質問
すでに解決したので困っていませんが、後学のために質問させていただきます。

ファイルを削除した後にすぐファイルが作成されてしまう（ただし空ファイル）という状況は、何が原因なのでしょうか？WSL上のファイルをWindowsのプロセスが掴んでいるかと思ったのですが、それならファイルは削除できなさそうです。
Windowsを再起動したら解決しましたが、できれば再起動せずに、特定のプロセスを終了させて解決したかったです。もっと良い解決方法や調査方法があれば教えていただきたいです。


二つ確認させてください。①ディストリビューションのバージョンはいくつですか？ wsl -l -v の結果を教えてください。②エクスプローラーで操作したとありますが、その時のパスは「C:...」とWindows上でのパスですが？それとも「\wsl.local...」とWSL専用の共有からですか？

① wsl -l -v の結果を追記しました。
②ファイルエクスプローラで\\wsl.local\...というパスに対して操作しました。
